# Need help for wring xls file using object-to-excel.jar

Tags: java, excel, xls

i just recently discover one api which is javaobject-to-xls. i really like that and its working perfect. but i dont know how to write link(hiperlink) in cell. means it will show google but its actual value will be http://www.google.com.

Please check following link

http://erdyes.wordpress.com/2012/07/06/convert-object-to-excel-with-java/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can introduce a composite new field containing an Excel formula for a hyperlink. So you construct your object as usual and introduce a new field. Say you provide `urlName` and `urlValue`:

```
public class Website {
  private String urlName;
  private String urlValue;

  private String url; // new composite field

  public Website(String name, String value)
  {
      this.urlName = name;
      this.urlValue = value;
      this.url = "=HYPERLINK(\"" + urlValue + "\", \"" + urlName + "\")";
  } 
}
```

The correct formula will be written to the Excel sheet, but instead of directly interpreting the formula Excel will at first only show the formula (at least it does so in Excel 2007).

To evaluate the formula you need to focus the table cell in Excel and press Enter, so Excel evaluates the formula. Maybe somebody else does know a solution for that.

As far as I can tell there is no possibility to achieve what you're trying to do.

*// EDIT: I've edited the answer and completely changed it after a discussion with the questioner. The comments are therefore obsolete.*

Comment: but where. means as string i can not use this. i am making user defined object link and giving it to the ObjectToExcelFile.exportToExcel(objectlist, excelfileparameterconfig, fieldaliasmap);

Comment: Usually these libraries use the getter-Methods to fetch values. Your object has a field say: `private String url` and `private String urlName`. Then there is a method `public String getUrl()`, which would normally just return the field `url`. Now you modify the `getUrl()` method and `return "=HYPERLINK(\"" + this.url + "\", \"" + this.urlName + "\");` and put "url" in your mapping:  `fieldNameTitleMap.put(“url”, “URL”);`

Comment: THIS library is totally dependent on apache-poi. so just download jar file and check it. you will easily understand. from following link http://www.smallfiles.org/download/1168/object-to-excel.0.1.jar.html. there are just two classes.

Comment: That's what I'm saying. But you need to modify your object you want to store in XLS accordingly. Modify the getter-Method of your URL column/field to return the Excel formula instead of only the URL.

Comment: I've updated the answer to explain how this will work. Your mapping still contains the "url" as `fieldName`. The framework will automatically call `getUrl()` for your object. On the blog explaining how to do this, check the Person.java file. You will see the getter-Methods there as well.

Comment: its not working. i dont know why. i used following string "return "=HYPERLINK(\"" + this.urlvalue + "\", \"" + this.urlname + "\")"; ".

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18976/discussion-between-kshitij-and-peter-ilfrich)